# (React on Rails) The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, yarnpkg, react-on-rails

For those familiar with the react-on-rails gem, or more generally, yarn:

Just today I updated my Node version to 8.8.1 via Homebrew. Now, when I attempt to run `bundle && yarn && foreman start -f Procfile.dev` (or just yarn install), I get the following message:

> error react-webpack-rails-tutorial@0.0.1: The engine "node" is
>   incompatible with this module. Expected version "5.10.0".
>
> error Found incompatible module
>
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation
>   about this command.

This is likely a very simple issue I am running into, but I have been unable to fix it after a few hours of debugging.

I tried manually updating my Node version in package.json to be that on my computer (did not seem to take effect whatsoever), downgrading my version to 5.10.0 via Homebrew (but was unable to), and even upgrading to the latest version of the gem which meant installing webpack as well.

No matter what I did, my local server startup (`bundle && yarn && foreman start -f Procfile.dev`) still lead to the same error above. Any ideas for this poor soul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone running into this same issue, I have not found a solution for the underlying issue but I have found a temporary workaround.

Simply run

```
bundle && yarn --ignore-engines && foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

instead of

```
bundle && yarn && foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

I hope this helps someone else that may have found themselves stuck in the same situation!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your Node.js version. Try to

1. Clear NPM's cache:

`sudo npm cache clean -f`

2. Install a little helper called 'n'

`sudo npm install -g n`

3. Install latest stable Node.js version

`sudo n stable`

Answer (score 0):

I give you this list of checks to do from the [`react-webpack-rails-tutorial` github page](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial#basic-demo-setup)

> ## Basic Demo Setup
>
> 1. Be sure that you have Node installed! We suggest nvm, with node version v6.0 or above. See this article Updating and using nvm.
> 2. git clone git@github.com:shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.git
>      cd react-webpack-rails-tutorial
> 3. Check that you have Ruby 2.3.0 or greater
> 4. Check that you're using the right version of node. Run nvm list to check. Use 5.5 or greater.
> 5. Check that you have Postgres installed. Run which postgres to check.
>      Use 9.4 or greater.
> 6. Check that you have qmake installed. Run which qmake to check. If
>      missing, follow these instructions: Installing Qt and compiling
>      capybara-webkit
> 7. Check that you have Redis installed. Run which redis-server to
>      check. If missing, install with Homebrew (brew install redis) or
>      follow these instructions.
> 8. bundle install
> 9. brew install yarn
> 10. yarn
> 11. rake db:setup
> 12. foreman start -f Procfile.hot
> 13. Open a browser tab to http://localhost:3000 for the Rails app
>        example with HOT RELOADING
> 14. Try Hot Reloading steps below!
> 15. foreman start -f Procfile.static
> 16. Open a browser tab to http://localhost:3000 for the Rails app
>        example.
> 17. When you make changes, you have to refresh the browser page.

Comment: Hey Fabrizio, appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately this issue was encountered far after the tutorial and initial install. It appeared to only arise after upgrading node versions via Homebrew!